# pandas drop column based on condition on groupby

Tags: pandas, group-by

[I have a data like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsZqI.png)

I want to group by "Stok Kodu" column and sort by "Miktar" column then create table to another excel file.

When i use this code;

```
df = df.groupby(["Stok Kodu"]).sum(numeric_only = False)
df = df.sort_values("Miktar", ascending=False)
```

everything is okay. Here is output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHlbm.png)

After all this i want to creat table to another excel file but when i run all codes "Stok Kodu" drops in the table.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xcdl.png)

Here is my all codes:

````
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('siparislerr.xlsx')
df = df.groupby(["Stok Kodu"]).sum()
df = df.sort_values("Miktar", ascending=False)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_table21.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)


workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']


(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

column_settings = []
for header in df.columns:
    column_settings.append({'header': header})

worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col -1 , {'columns': column_settings})
worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 12)
writer.save()```
````

Comment: You might want to keep the grouper as column, try `df.groupby(["Stok Kodu"], as_index=False).sum(numeric_only = False)`

Comment: Thank you so much my friend. It drove me crazy but your line worked.